# Fail with error 'SafeMath: multiplication overflow' on mainet but works perfectly on testnet

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

My marketplace buy Function Works fine on testnets georli,ropsten,bsctestnet etc but displays Fail with error 'SafeMath: multiplication overflow' on mainnet

```
  function buyItem(
    uint256 id,
    address admin,
    uint256 serviceFeePercentage,
    uint256 value
)
    external
    ItemExists(id)
    IsForSale(id)
    HasTransferApproval(
        itemsForSale[id].tokenAddress,
        itemsForSale[id].tokenId
    )
{
    require(itemsForSale[id].active, "Item is no longer on sale");
    require(!itemsForSale[id].isSold, "Item is sold");
    require(value >= itemsForSale[id].askingPrice, "Not enough funds sent");
    require(msg.sender != itemsForSale[id].seller);

    itemsForSale[id].isSold = true;
    itemsForSale[id].active = false;
    activeItemsActivator(
        itemsForSale[id].tokenAddress,
        itemsForSale[id].tokenId,
        false
    );

    purchase(id, admin, serviceFeePercentage, value, msg.sender, false);
}
```

Purchase Function

```
function purchase(
    uint256 id,
    address admin,
    uint256 serviceFeePercentage,
    uint256 value,
    address buyer,
    bool bid
) private {
    uint256 serviceFee = mul((value * 10**18),serviceFeePercentage) / 100;
    uint256 pay = sub(mul(value,10**18),serviceFee);

    if (bid) {
        IERC721(itemsForBid[id].tokenAddress).safeTransferFrom(
            itemsForBid[id].seller,
            buyer,
            itemsForBid[id].tokenId
        );
        IERC20(tracker_0x_address).transfer(itemsForBid[id].seller, pay);
        IERC20(tracker_0x_address).transfer(admin, serviceFee);
    } else {
        IERC721(itemsForSale[id].tokenAddress).safeTransferFrom(
            itemsForSale[id].seller,
            buyer,
            itemsForSale[id].tokenId
        );
        IERC20(tracker_0x_address).transferFrom(
            buyer,
            itemsForSale[id].seller,
            pay
        );
        IERC20(tracker_0x_address).transferFrom(buyer, admin, serviceFee);
    }
    emit itemSold(id, buyer, value, bid);
}
```

already deployed many times and still not working on mainnet

Comment: What values you pass as the `serviceFeePercentage` and `value` when the error occurs?

Comment: I passed 2 as serviceFeePercentage

Comment: The thing is me and my team tested on test net and it works fine I only have this issue on mainet

Comment: Value is 20 sir

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out it's a decimal issue the token decimal is 9 but am multiplying by 18

it works on testnet because I deployed a token with 18 decimal